# I visited a hacked website! Should I be worried? What should I do now?

Tags: security, malware, websites

**I am concerned about the security when I run Ubuntu without an anti-virus and visit a hacked website. I feel that this question then should be asked here and not anywhere else. I can't seem to comprehend why it has attracted a lot of close flags and negative up-votes.**

---

I don't have an antivirus running on my laptop. I run an regularly updated **Ubuntu 14.04** on it. I unintentionally visited a hacked website:

[image]

I got a bit concerned and I tried visiting the same website on a Mac laptop with an antivirus running. The anti-virus stopped me from visiting the page and warned me that it is a malicious/hacked website.

I would like to ask two questions.

1) Should I be concerned about my laptop's (which runs on Ubuntu without an Anti-virus) security at the moment? Is there a chance of mine getting infected?

2) Whether I got infected or not this time, what can be done to reducing the probability that next time, if I end up accidentally visiting a hacked website, I don't get infected?

Comment: This has nothing to do with ubuntu. I think this question should be asked on [Information security](https://security.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I feel that it has everything to do with Ubuntu because the question is revolving around the security of Ubuntu, not just any other OS.

Comment: @daltonfury42: because you mentioned "Mac" people here think you did this on a Mac, not an Ubuntu system.  Please [edit] your answer and clarify...  (AFAI understood you did this from an Ubuntu system and then used the Mac as a test system afterwards)

Comment: @Fabby Feeling a bit pissed off here. I thought I mentioned it right in the second line itself. Thanks for pointing it out anyway.

Comment: I agree, this did not deserve -5, I voted it up one but voting is +2/-6 and I doubt most of these users will revisit the question, to revise there vote. I also don't see this as off topic, the question could be worded better sure but it is essentially `how can I protect Ubuntu from viruses ?`I am surprised to see the high rep users on the close reason, can someone please explain where in the `help` it says this is off topic ? I vote to reopen.

Comment: @daltonfury42:  For the record: I never downvoted nor cast a close vote.  I just explained what was *probably* happening...  **;-)**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No one here can say if you are infected, we don't have access to your computer.

All I can say is most viruses are for Windows, the chance is low, but it is a chance non the less.

The course of action I would recommend for you is, use an anti virus program on Ubuntu to scan it. This one is free and open source `clamav`

```
sudo apt-get install clamav
```

Update its database

```
sudo freshclam
```

Scan your whole system with

```
clamscan -r /
```

Or a single folder

```
clamscan -r /home
```

For some `real-time` protection, you can install the daemon, it will run automatic at boot

```
sudo apt-get install clamav-daemon
```

Sample output

```
----------- SCAN SUMMARY -----------
Known viruses: 33840
Scanned directories: 145
Scanned files: 226
Infected files: 1
Data scanned: 54.22 MB
I/O buffer size: 131072 bytes
Time: 20.831 sec (0 m 20 s)
```

Here is [some documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ClamAV), it is dated but it works. Tested on 14.04.

Comment: No worries, if you want `real time` protection, install `clamav-deamon`, I missed it off the answer, will edit it later.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to remove malware , as it's often mentioned on security.stackexchange.com , is to nuke it from the orbit - in other words reinstall the whole OS. However, that might be a bit of an overkill.

Here are couple of suggestions I personally would use:

- Reboot your computer, and on fresh login , don't open the browser.
  Run `sudo netstat -tulpan` to check for any fishy connections and IP
  addresses that belong to sites other than `Canonical's`.  You can
  check ip-addresses with `nslookup  <ip-address-here>` command.
- Most malware is for Windows, so unless you ran your browser with root
  permissions (`sudo` or `gksu`), there shouldn't be that much
  possibility for your system being infected. But just in case you can
  check processes that are running with `ps -ef | less` command. Cannot
  tell  you what exactly to look for, just anything fishy.
- You could remove your browser profile,also, as a security measure.
  For instance, `~/.mozilla/firefox` if you are a firefox user.
  Whatever malicious cache and cookies could have been there, will be
  gone.  Note that bookmarks will be gone. You might want to export
  them to an html file, before you nuke your profile.
- Change password with `passwd` command.
- Get into your home router (if that's where you've browsed from) and change/set admin password as well as change your wifi password

Comment: Why did you not mention installing an AV?

Comment: @daltonfury42 because mark kirby already mentioned that in his answer :)

Comment: If you include that a point in your answer, I could accept it as the answer.